# Java Regex Group Replacement Without Matching Group Offset Manipulation

Tags: java, regex

I often face requirements like removing `<p></p>` tags from within an XHTML document, for a very specific type of subsequence.  (One that disallows the use of `String.replaceAll()`).  Typically its of the pattern `<p>${randomTextAndHTMLorJavascript}</p>` but the one constant is that its always one arbitrary tag with lots of crap, followed by its ending tag. No tag nesting!

My question is if anyone is aware of a higher-level abstraction other than manually manipulating the `Matcher` object.  In the past I've done these kinds of replacements:

1. Treating the problem as an array copy, where I use a `StringBuilder` object and use the `Matcher.start(int)` and `Matcher.end(int)` methods to NOT copy the target group(s) from the input `String`.  This works, but feels like C, not Java.
2. Do a loop where I use the start token to find the first tag and take the result of `match1.group()` as input for the second `Matcher` to capture the end tag, and then use `Matcher.replaceFirst()` to handle the replacement in the input string itself.  This has a drawback of needing to call `Matcher.reset()` forcing a reparse.  (I only use this for throwaway scripts or if the input set is guaranteed to be tiny.)
3. `String.split()` on one tag, replacing it except when matched by `match1` and reconstructing the string with `StringBuilder`.  Run the second `Matcher` against a token representing the end tag's sequence and do a `String.replaceAll()` before appending.
4. I've also tried using the `StringBuilder.deleteCharAt()` method, but still feels too low-level for a language like Java.

What would be ideal would be a method signature like this:

```
Matcher.replaceGroup(int targetGroup, String pattern, String replacement);
```

Ultimately I'm hoping to replace a regex matching group in Java without needing to work with group/array offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XHTML (or other XML) documents, one (much) higher-level abstraction would be an XSL transform.  They are far more expressive and powerful than regex, and they can work even if you *do* have internal structure to contend with.

Or if you want to keep the logic closer to Java, then why not use backreferences in the replacement string:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(<p>keep )(stuff I don't want)( this</p>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

// Replace matches to the pattern with the same thing less "stuff I don't want":
String output = m.replaceAll("$1$3");
```

I know you said you can't use `replaceAll()`, but it's not clear to me why you could not accomplish exactly what you describe in your (1) (for example) via this approach.

Of course, backreferences work with `Matcher.replaceFirst()`, `String.replaceAll()` and `String.replaceFirst()`, too.

*Edited to add:*

If you want to step through iteratively, to do something more with the matches as they go by, then you should look into `Matcher.appendReplacement()` (with which you can also use backreferences) and `Matcher.appendTail()`.

Comment: The issue was a naked `String.replaceAll()` not something like what you just pulled off.  That was nice!

Comment: Would this technique (on a large string) still require you to reset the `Matcher` thus forcing a reparse of the (now changed) `String?`

Comment: @avgvstvs I'm not sure I understand the question about resetting the `Matcher`.  You can use `replaceAll()`, as shown, to perform the match & replace globally, but the result is a different `String`, since Java `String`s are immutable.  If you want subsequently to perform another replacement then you need to `reset()` the `Matcher` to its new input.

Comment: `Matcher.replaceAll()` is going to alter the `Matcher` state, correct?  Since we're truncating the `String`, we would have to call `Matcher.reset()` in order to re-scan the input again, recreating the problem I listed in the OP as soln #2. Every call to `Matcher.reset()` forces a reparse. That means for however many tokens, we're parsing this XHTML that many times.

Comment: Yes, `Matcher.replaceAll()` alters the `Matcher`'s state, but what do you suppose you otherwise could do with it afterward?  `replaceAll()` will produce a result (a new `String`) in which *every occurrence* of the `Matcher's` pattern has been replaced, which as far as I can tell is what you wanted.

Comment: You could also consider processing the input one match at a time with `appendReplacement()`, finishing off with `appendTail()`.  That's more flexible, and it does avoid reparsing the string from the beginning at each step.  I edited my answer to mention those.

Comment: You can tell I was chasing shadows here... I missed that `Matcher.replaceAll()` worked on the *entire* `String` as well as oblivious to the fact that it would take backreferences as args.  This is everything I was looking for!